# Dynamically Updating Menus Based On Previously Picked Menu Items

Tags: java, php, html, dynamic, menu

So I'm thinking of making an NFL Team Pick 'em Google Sheet for my co-workers and I to use this upcoming NFL season.  Every week, we will pick an NFL team to win a game and we can only pick each team once.  1 point for every correctly picked  game.  Most points wins the pot.

I need some help with how to pick the team each week so that you can only pick a team once.  I'm not sure if this is possible in a Google Sheet.  If so, how can I have someone pick a team from all 32 NFL teams the first week, then the menu for week two automatically excludes the pick from week 1.  Then week 3 automatically excludes the pick from both weeks 1 and 2 and so on.

Or would a project like this be better suited in PHP/Java/HTML?  If so, how would I handle the same menu principles in PHP?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.

I have one column that lists all the nfl teams K4:K35.

I have a data validation cell A4 that looks at the nfl teams on K4:K35.

In cell A24 I put the formula "=filter(K4:K35,K4:K35<>A4)" that filters the nfl team list K4:K35 except for the week 1 pick in cell A4.

I then have a data validation cell B4 that looks at the A22:A55 list for users to pick for week 2.

In cell A24 I put the formula "=filter(K4:K35,(K4:K35<>B4)*(K4:K35<>A4))" that filters the nfl team list K4:K35 except for the week 1 pick in cell A4 week 2 pick of B4.

Lather rinse repeat, and hide some columns and rows.  One sheet for each participant.  I'll add point totals with a master point total sheet too later on.

Jerome